# How to validate edit text field to allow user enter only text input in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to validate the text field to input only text. No numeric or special characters allowed.

Comment: in the XML, add this:...

 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one bro**

```
android:digits=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

set edittext property with capital and small

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex, validate users input. Use the following function:

```
public boolean AlphaCheck(String name) {
            return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
        }
```

Send the string(users input) to this function and if the input is valid it will return true and you can then proceed based on that.

Here is another way to do it

```
public boolean AlphaCheck(String name) {
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

for (char c : chars) {
    if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter for this

`private String unwantedChars = "~#^|$%&*!1234567890";`

```
private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
      Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source != null && unwantedChars.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

`editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });`